# How to place two figures side by side with subcaption?

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to display two figures next to each other with captions using subfigures but it keeps placing one under the other.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{apparatus.jpg}
\caption{A photograph of the apparatus used}
\label{fig:capparatus}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\def\svgwidth{0.7\linewidth}
\input{diagram.pdf_tex}
%\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{diagram.pdf}
\caption{A diagram of the apparatus sited inside the evacuated chamber}
\label{fig:cdiagram}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{A graphical depiction of the setup}
\label{fig:csetup}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have tried:

- Changing from pdf_tex to just including the pdf file (generated from inkscape)
- Adding [h] and [b] to the subfigures
- Adding a % after the first and second subfigures
- Changing the sizes of the subfigures and images

but nothing seems to make them display on the same line. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my output with pdf_tex:

[image: With pdf_tex]

And with just the pdf:

[image: Without pdf_tex]

Comment: Trailing spaces: Remove them: `\end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}`

Comment: In addition to "Adding a % after the first and second subfigures": did you also remove the empty line between them?

Comment: Yes, the trailing whitespace seemed to be the issue. Thank you both.

Comment: you have a blank line which is a paragraph break so forced vertical stacking  it is the same layout as you get with letters `xx` side by side  `x<newline>x` a space between them `x<newline><newline>x`  two paragraphs and vertically stacked x

Answer (score 3):

To display images side by side it is preferable to use the subfig  package instead of the subcaption package.
You must not put a space between the two calls to subfloat

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering
\subfloat[A photograph of the apparatus used]{\label{fig:capparatus}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{apparatus.jpg}
}
%no space
\hfill
\subfloat[A diagram of the apparatus sited inside the evacuated chamber]{\label{fig:cdiagram}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{diagram.pdf}
}

\caption{A graphical depiction of the setup}
\label{fig:csetup}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `subfig`package is not preferable for placing figures side-by-side. This can be dan also with  the `subcaption` package (with all advantages over `subfig`) and use `subfigure` environments. You only need to take a care, that between code for  `subfigure`s is not empty line and space.

Comment: subfigure package is Deprecated?
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure

Comment: `sibfigure ` package is deprecated, but not `subfigure` environment defined in the `subcaption` package which has some advantages over `subfig` package as better control of environment, less problems with hyper referencing. I just like to say, that use `subfloat` environment is not preferable over `sunfigure`. Interestingly, `subcaption` can be used for defined both of them.

Comment: Thank you, I will try, but at the moment I have no notable concerns

Answer (score 1):

For exercise:

- As was already mentioned, the cause of your problems is trailing space code between both `subfigure`s. You only need to remove it as suggested in @Sigur comment: `**`**
- Off-topic:

  - `hyperref` had to be with rare exception (as is `cleveref` package) had to be loaded lat in preamble (because it must correct the settings of other packages that will work properly).
  - since both images have equal width, you can use keys `Gin` for define it
  - you can have shorter code if prescribe narrower width for `subfigure` and equal image width to it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}   % had to loaded last

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{apparatus.jpg}
\caption{A photograph of the apparatus used}
\label{fig:capparatus}
\end{subfigure}% trailing space between `subfigure` environments  had to be removed
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{diagram.pdf}
\caption{A diagram of the apparatus sited inside the evacuated chamber}
\label{fig:cdiagram}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A graphical depiction of the setup}
\label{fig:csetup}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]